# ag-Grid: toolPanel is only available in ag-Grid Enterprise

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I am using Angular2 version.I am getting below error, when I am trying to upgrade to ag-grid-enterprise version. Written below code for setting up license key.

import { LicenseManager } from 'ag-grid-enterprise';
LicenseManager.setLicenseKey(xxx);

But I am getting the below error, when ever I am trying to use "ToolPanel" (enterprise) functionality,

'ag-Grid: toolPanel is only available in ag-Grid Enterprise.

Need your help on this, I have searched entire web and tried restarting the system and other measures suggested in the forum, but every time I am getting the above error.

Appreciate your help on this.

Comment: Have you imported ag grid enterprise?

import "ag-grid-enterprise";

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps below for Enterprise ag-grid

1. npm install --save ag-grid-enterprise ag-grid-angular
2. Add import { AgGridModule } from 'ag-grid-angular';  import
   'ag-grid-enterprise'; to app.module.ts